# How to filter in the where clause, on a column that is within the select statement and contains count/distinct/case/when

Tags: sql, hadoop, where-clause

Using SQL on hadoop.

I have a list of IDs where i am trying to count the total number of 2 types of different guest review data points. For `guest_review_1` i have returned the total. For `guest_review_2` i have split the total counts into 5 ranges.

What I am struggling with is to set a filter in the where clause of `guest_review_1` where by I dont include properties that had a total count of less than 5.

Any ideas of a workaround? Nested Select statements maybe?

Included a sample of the query below:

```
Select 
id,
count(distinct guest_review_1) as "Guest_Reviews",
count(distinct(case when guest_review_2 < 1 then guest_review_1 end)) as Group1,
Count(distinct(case when guest_review_2 >=2 AND guest_review_2 <3 then guest_review_1 end)) as Group2,
From  table_name
Where
guest_review_2 IS NOT NULL
AND guest_review_1 >=5
AND date BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-01-31'
Group By id
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely certain on the meaning of the `group_1` and `group_2` aggregates in your sample query.  However, the essence of your question seems to be about how to filter a result set based on the results of an aggregate function (`count`) rather than filtering on values of individual input rows.  Apache Hive supports this by using the SQL [`HAVING`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Select#LanguageManualSelect-HAVINGClause) clause.

In the following example, the input relation contains 6 rows with `id` set to `1` and 4 rows with `id` set to `2`.  The query includes the clause `HAVING guest_reviews >= 5`.  Because of the `HAVING` clause, the result set contains only a row for `id` with `1`.  There is no output row with `id` set to to `2`.

```
WITH table_name AS (
    SELECT 1 AS id, 1 AS guest_review_1, 1 AS guest_review_2 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 AS id, 2 AS guest_review_1, 2 AS guest_review_2 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 AS id, 3 AS guest_review_1, 3 AS guest_review_2 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 AS id, 4 AS guest_review_1, 4 AS guest_review_2 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 AS id, 5 AS guest_review_1, 5 AS guest_review_2 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 AS id, 6 AS guest_review_1, 6 AS guest_review_2 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS id, 1 AS guest_review_1, 1 AS guest_review_2 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS id, 2 AS guest_review_1, 2 AS guest_review_2 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS id, 3 AS guest_review_1, 3 AS guest_review_2 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS id, 4 AS guest_review_1, 4 AS guest_review_2
)
SELECT
    id,
    count(DISTINCT guest_review_1) AS guest_reviews,
    count(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN guest_review_2 < 1 THEN guest_review_1 END)) AS group_1,
    count(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN guest_review_2 >= 2 AND guest_review_2 < 3 THEN guest_review_1 END)) as group_2
FROM table_name
WHERE guest_review_2 IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY id
HAVING guest_reviews >= 5
;
```